# Forcing attribute change using attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to force the change of two twitter feed attributes in order to change the displayed feed based on a drop down selection. Below is part of the function to change the needed attributes, but I cant seem to get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated;

EDIT: I appreciate the help. I'm relatively new to coding and this is pretty much the first thing I've done on my own, rookie mistakes and all :)

```
$("#twitterselector")
                    .onchange(switch($("#twitterselector").val()) {
                    case X:
                        $("#twitterfeed").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/Sample");
                        $("#twitterfeed").attr("data-user-id", "012345678");
                        break;
```

Comment: `onchange` expects a function, and you aren´t giving one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the target element as `this` in the callback function you provide:

```
  $("#twitterselector").change(function(){
            switch($(this).val()) {
            case "X":
               $("#twitterfeed").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/Sample");
               $("#twitterfeed").attr("data-user-id", "012345678");
               break;
            }
   });
```

You can also combine the attrs together as they target the same element:

```
   $("#twitterfeed").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/Sample").attr("data-user-id", "012345678");
```

Comment: where does your switch end? :D

Comment: @Jaak Kütt: there... right there :) Initially I did not bother to close the code at all as the original is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I know there's a bunch of mistakes, but I'm trying to learn. This is pretty much my first foray too.

Answer (score 0):

Some heavy syntax errors above. `onchange` is a DOM function, you have a jQuery object. It also expects a function:

```
$("#twitterselector").change(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    switch(value) {
        case X:
            $("#twitterfeed").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/Sample");
            $("#twitterfeed").attr("data-user-id", "012345678");
            break;
    }
});
```